# 2 animations on same model problem

Tags: animation, unreal-engine

I am using latest version of Blender (2.75a) and I'm having a problem with animation.

I have one animation in the Dope Sheet and it's working as it should, but I am unable to make another one on the same model. I did save it in the Action Editor, but when I return to Dope Sheet and delete all of keyframes, then insert new ones, the first animation doesn't work. I also tried with Blender (2.71) and it didn't worked, but I did the same thing with another model a few months back in 2.71 and it worked just fine

If anyone knows how to fix it I would be really grateful.

***SOLVED:***

I removed ALL empties and IK's I had in my mesh and I enabled Auto-IK and Auto Keyframing

I made an Action1 in Action Editor and went back to Dope Sheet where I placed my keyframes for the first action.When I was done with that I went to Action Editor and created Action2 and again went back to Dope Sheet where I placed keyframes for second animation

Everything works as it should and no problems whatsoever

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! It sounds like you want to have multiple animations on one object (that blend together?). Have you looked into using the NLA editor at all?

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question with how you solved it, that'll take it off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

To add a Second animation you have to change first to **Action Editor** at the bottom from **Dope Sheet**

[image]

and then press the **New** button at the bottom:

[image]

And now you can Animate and switching between your animations

EDIT: After you created an Animatin you should press the "**x**" Button next to it and then press new:

[image]

and then press the new button:

[image]

It should work

Comment: As I said,I did that but it doesn't work for some reason

Comment: You said that you have been deleting some keyframes, but that is in no need

Comment: I did that what you suggested so I have Walking Action,it's working great so I make another Action called Attacking and  return to Dope Sheet but there are still keyframes from Walking one so I need to delete them but when I do that Walking Action is no longer working

I have to go now but I'll post screenshots later today to help you realise my problem

Comment: See my answer and try it again, also try restarting your Blender. If that doesn help, could you upload your blend file

Comment: Didn't worked,could I add you on Skype to give share my .blend file

Comment: For cases like that there is a website, No Registry. Just Drag your file > provide a link to your question > press Upload > and paste the link in your question.     http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m0txj7zuvzonv25/finalspider.blend?dl=0

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: To me it seems that as there are many separate objects animated, in Action Editor you should create a New Separate Action for each one: Select the Empties and create new Action, then select the Rig(bones) and create new action etc...    But when you go back to the Dope Sheet it shows animations of all objects,  thats why when you delete all of the, it doesn't work

Comment: Can I select all of the empties and make one action for all of them and then for the armature?

I don't really get what I should do,it automatically creates (ex.)Empty5Action in action editor

Comment: yeah i know and unfortunately what I can think about now is for you to add a new Action to every single empy individualy

Comment: It still doesn't work
Is it anyhow possible that you make  just two simple animations that I can afterwards modify? 
Or to give me step by step tutorial?
Thank you